# Initializer does not override a designated initializer while subclassing NSURLSession Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, subclassing, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I want to subclass NSURLSession class, but I have problem with initialisation.
Basically I override the constructor and initialising the constant `authUrl` there then calling the parent init method.

```
class NSURLAuthSession: NSURLSession {
    let authUrl:NSURL;

    //Error: Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
    override init(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?, delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?){
        self.authUrl = NSURL.URLWithBaseURLString("http://192.168.10.105:8888/api/v1", pathSegments: ["users", "login"])!
        super.init(configuration: configuration, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: queue)
    }
}
```

From the source code of NSURLSession I found out that it has two initializers:

```
public /*not inherited*/ init(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration)
public /*not inherited*/ init(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?, delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?)
```

I expected the "longest" init to be the designated initializer but it's not.
I suspect that that designated initializer is the `init()` that is not even specified in the source code. 
How can I override the initializer and set up the configuration `NSURLSessionConfiguration`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not.

The only designated initializer is `NSURLSession.init()` and you must call it from your subclass initializer. `NSURLSession` `configuration`, `delegate` and `delegateQueue` properties are read-only so you can not manually set them.

The better way is to wrap `NSURLSession` with custom class:

```
class NSURLAuthSession {
    private let urlSession: NSURLSession

    init(urlSession: NSURLSession) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
    }
}
```

thus you will have more control and customization options.

Comment: Thanks for the response, just for clarification, the NSSession can be initialised with configuration and delegate but its subclass  NSURLAuthSession cannot?

Comment: Yes, because subclass must call superclass designated initializer. You can read more about designated and convenience initializers hear https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that only "dummy" initializer is exposed is that the developers of UIKit don't want you to subclass NSURLSession. If you just want to provide your own URL, write a convenience method on NSURLSession or just configure it yourself using the existing API.

Comment: In order to add convenience method I  need to  subclass the NSURLSession (that is not recommended) right?

Comment: No-no-no, just wriete an extension to NSURLSession. Like follows: extension NSURLSession { /*my convenience methods and stuff*/}. Unfortunately, you won't be able to add any stored properties to the target class. I hope now my advice is not ambiguous. :)

Comment: Also, just in case (should be obvious), I don't refer to the convenience keyword :)