# crash in swift code: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a command line Swift application that makes an HTTP request. As a side note, I want to provide a session to the application's `run` func so that I can use dependency injection to unit test the code (hence the protocol I defined).

This crashes with "unrecognized selector sent to instance." What does this mean?

```
//
//  main.swift
//  MockIt
//
//

import Foundation

public protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func synchronousDataTask( _ url: URL ) -> ( Data?, URLResponse?, Error? )
}

class MyUrlSession : URLSession, URLSessionProtocol {

    func synchronousDataTask( _ url: URL ) -> ( Data?, URLResponse?, Error? ) {
        var data: Data?
        var response: URLResponse?
        var error: Error?

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        let dataTask = self.dataTask(with: url) {
            data = $0
            response = $1
            error = $2

            semaphore.signal()
        }
        dataTask.resume()

        _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)

        return (data, response, error)
    }

}

class MyModule {
    func run( _ session: URLSessionProtocol, _ urlString: String ) {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let ( _, response, _ ) =
            session.synchronousDataTask(url!)
        print( response! )
    }
}


MyModule().run( MyUrlSession(), "https://myapiendpoint.com" )
```

The full crash is here:

```
2017-04-12 11:29:07.930076 MockIt[33267:1871173] -[MockIt.MyUrlSession dataTaskForRequest:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100a043d0
2017-04-12 11:29:07.933897 MockIt[33267:1871173] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MockIt.MyUrlSession dataTaskForRequest:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100a043d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff785dfe7b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d1c0cad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff78661cb4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff78551fb5 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff78551b08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MockIt                              0x000000010000177d _TFC6MockIt12MyUrlSession19synchronousDataTaskfV10Foundation3URLTGSqVS1_4Data_GSqCSo11URLResponse_GSqPs5Error___ + 477
    6   MockIt                              0x0000000100001bf8 _TTWC6MockIt12MyUrlSessionS_18URLSessionProtocolS_FS1_19synchronousDataTaskfV10Foundation3URLTGSqVS2_4Data_GSqCSo11URLResponse_GSqPs5Error___ + 72
    7   MockIt                              0x0000000100001d1d _TFC6MockIt8MyModule3runfTPS_18URLSessionProtocol_SS_T_ + 253
    8   MockIt                              0x0000000100001584 main + 116
    9   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8daa4255 start + 1
    10  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Not sure if it matters, but this is the general structure of my app directory:

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── DerivedData
│   ├── Build
│   ├── MockIt
│   └── ModuleCache
├── MockIt
├── MockIt-Bridging-Header.h
├── MockIt.xcodeproj
│   ├── project.pbxproj
│   ├── project.xcworkspace
│   └── xcuserdata
├── MockItTest
│   ├── Info.plist
│   └── MockItTest.swift
└── main.swift
```

Answer (score 1):

`URLSession` isn't designed to be subclassed.

I think the problem you are seeing stems from the fact that you aren't fully initialising the `URLSession` subclass.  You're calling `init()`, when `URLSession` is meant to be initialised with at least a configuration object via `init(configuration:)`.

You cannot call those initialisers yourself from the subclass because they have been specially marked as not inheritable.

You cannot assign to the configuration property yourself, because it's a read-only properly.

You might be able to trick your way around this by overriding the property, but it's almost certainly a better idea to not subclass `URLSession`.  Have  you considered doing this as an extension instead?

There's a little more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950213/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-while-subclassing-nsurlse).