# Subclassing URLSession - 'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, subclassing, urlsession

I would like to create a subclass of URLSession, but I get a warning:

> 'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Please use +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:] or other class methods to create instances

How can I do this:

> Please use +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:]

I'm trying to implement a simple class for mocking a URLSession:

```swift
class WeatherURLSessionFake: URLSession {
     
     var data: Data?
     var response: URLResponse?
     var error: Error?
     
     init(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
          self.data = data
          self.response = response
          self.error = error
     }
 => warning : 'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Please use +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:] or other class methods to create instances
     
     override func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
         let task = WeatherURLSessionDataTaskFake()
         task.completionHandler = completionHandler
         task.data = data
         task.urlResponse = response
         task.responseError = error
         return task
     }
 => warning : 'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Please use +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:] or other class methods to create instances
     
     override func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
         let task = WeatherURLSessionDataTaskFake()
         task.completionHandler = completionHandler
         task.data = data
         task.urlResponse = response
         task.responseError = error
         return task
     }
 => warning : 'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Please use +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:] or other class methods to create instances
}
```

Comment: Putting your problem aside, it's generally difficult to mock system classes. It' easier to wrap URLSession calls into a custom object and mock that. Or, run a mock server instead and only change the URL to call that mock server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializer does not override a designated initializer while subclassing NSURLSession Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950213/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-while-subclassing-nsurlse)

Comment: See linked. Don't subclass, use with custom config, or custom behavior

Comment: thank you for responding to my post. I followed @akjndklskver's recommendation. I was able to advance for URLSession but a new problem appears with URLSessionDataTask see if you wish it : https://www.google.com/search?q=translator+french+english&rlz=1C5CHFA_enFR759FR759&oq=translator+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0i20i131i263i433i512j0i131i433i512l8.8740j0i&sourceid=chrome&chrome&sourceidj0j0i UTF-8
Thanks again.

Comment: thank you for responding to my post. I followed @akjndklskver's recommendation. I was able to advance for URLSession but a new problem appears with URLSessionDataTask see if you wish it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434209/swift-subclassing-urlsessiondatatask-which-super-initdatataskfakewrapper-u
Thanks again.