# Swift - Subclassing URLSessionDataTask - Which super.init(DataTaskFakeWrapper: URLSessionDataTask ?????????) Apply?

Tags: ios, swift, subclassing

I'm trying to subclass a URLSessionDataTask as shown in this post [Initializer does not override a designated initializer while subclassing NSURLSession Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950213/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-while-subclassing-nsurlse/) Except that the sub class init imposes a super.init back to the parent class. Here is the code :

```
class DataTaskFakeWrapper {
 let DataTaskFakeWrapper: URLSessionDataTask
  init(DataTaskFakeWrapper: URLSessionDataTask) {
      self.DataTaskFakeWrapper = DataTaskFakeWrapper
 }
```

}

```
class DataTaskFake: DataTaskFakeWrapper {
 var completionHandler: ((Data, URLResponse, Error) -> Void)?
 var data: Data
 var urlResponse: URLResponse
 var responseError: Error
 init( data: Data, urlResponse: URLResponse, responseError: Error) {
      self.data = data
      self.urlResponse = urlResponse
      self.responseError = responseError
      super.init(DataTaskFakeWrapper:
                     URLSessionDataTask)
  }
 
 func resume() {
      completionHandler?(data, urlResponse, responseError)
 }
 
 func cancel() {
      // not applicable
 }
```

}

The message
"Cannot convert value of type 'URLSessionDataTask.Type' to expected argument type 'URLSessionDataTask" appears and I can't find the right type to communicate from my sub class :

```
super.init(DataTaskFakeWrapper:
                     URLSessionDataTask)
```

and avoid that message : "Cannot convert value of type 'URLSessionDataTask.Type' to expected argument type 'URLSessionDataTask"

With a similar subclassing of URLSession, the super.int allows the URLSession(configuration: .default) argument.

What is the one for URLSessionDataTask in my case. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no such thing for URLSessionDataTask. You cannot generate them without a URLSession. (Note that in both the example you list and your code, these are not subclasses; they're wrappers.) But what would you do with this? Why does this type require a data task?

Comment: Manu thanks @Rob Napier for your answer. All start at this point with simple yellow warnings "Deprecated ...." but nobody seems say "Replace by ..." and I can't find it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74406895/subclassing-urlsession-init-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0

Comment: Right; you cannot subclass URLSession or any of the related types. What are you trying to do with such as subclass? If you want something that returns data for an URLRequest without talking to the network, use a protocol. I describe a Transport protocol here: https://robnapier.net/a-mockery-of-protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inside the `DataTaskFakeWrapper` class your `DataTaskFakeWrapper` property should be typed in camel case so `dataTaskFakeWrapper` to avoid confusion of being a type itself
2. Inside the `DataTaskFake` `super.init` call you're not initializing the object, just trying to pass the type. Right now it should be

```swift
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.my-fake-url.com")))
super.init(
  DataTaskFakeWrapper: DataTaskFakeWrapper(
    DataTaskFakeWrapper: dataTask
  )
)
```

This also shows you why it's good to name the property using camel case.

It would also be great to stub the networking code so that your tests are not making real network requests (resulting in flaky results). You can read more about implementing `URLProtocol` and then registering your "fake server" using `URLProtocol.registerClass`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @dziobaczy I will follow your recommendations.

Comment: Sure happy to help if something is unclear, feel free to ask here so others can benefit too

Comment: Thanks @dziobaczy for this very thorough answer.
1) You are absolutely right about camelCase's flaws. It's my fault, because I shortened the variable names for readability, but without converting the first letter to lowercase :(
2) Your solution works fine, except for your "super.init(
DataTaskFakeWrapper: DataTaskFakeWrapper(
    DataTaskFakeWrapper: dataTask
  )" that turned it into "super.init(
DataTaskFakeWrapper: dataTask
  )" and no more errors!
Many thanks and one more vote.

Comment: You're welcome, Oh yeah my solution after the change won't work due to a reason you wrote about, thats why I wrote above the code snippert "Right now it should be" but that could be not clear enough sorry, and glad to hear you got it working!